# C#: EventHandler delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

In the above code, EventHandler is a delegate which accepts `object sender, EventArgs e`. However, the number of arguments do not match in the below implementation:

```
this.baptismApplication_add_button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.baptismApplication_add_button_Click);
```

I can see that the `sender` is `this.baptismApplication_add_button_Click`, but which part of the method calls has `EventArgs e` ? Is it implicit? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delegate` are special types. They represent *methods*. This:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

does *not* mean that to create an `EventHandler`, you need to pass in two arguments `sender` and `e`. It simply means

> `EventHandler` represents a method with the signature of `(object sender, EventArgs e)` returning `void`.

To create a `EventHandler`, you need to pass in a method that has the required signature. For example, this method:

```
private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

You can create an `EventHandler` like this:

```
new EventHandler(MyMethod);
```

Note how I did not write `()` after the method name. Doing so would call the method. We don't want that. Here we just want to *refer* to it.

Let's look at another example.

```
public delegate void Action();
```

To create an `Action`, you need a method that has no arguments and returns `void`. Like this:

```
private void MyMethod2() {}
// ...
new Action(MyMethod2);
```

Now that you understood how delegates work, we can talk about how to subscribe to the `Click` event properly.

As I've said, `EventHandler`'s "constructor" takes a method as argument, so you shouldn't pass your button in there. You need a method. Let's write one:

```
private void ButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Now we can create the delegate with this method:

```
yourButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.ButtonPressed);
```

This can actually be shortened to:

```
yourButton.Click += ButtonPressed;
```

Now every time you press the button "Hello World" will be printed.

Comment: In which part does the sender and EventArgs get passed as argument? I can't seem to find it in my code

Comment: @DonovanKeating Haha, good question. The actual calling of `ButtonPress` is not done by you. It's done by the button's code. You just give a method for the button to call when it is pressed. That's why it's called "delegate". You just need to give it a method with the correct signature.

Comment: So I can't actually see it cuz it's "hidden"? If I make my own EventHandler, I'll have to specify the sender and EventArgs right? :)

Comment: @DonovanKeating Somewhere in `Button`'s code, it calls `Click.Invoke(this, new EventArgs())`. See the two arguments passed? You'll only have to pass the two arguments if you made a class that raises an event. Just search for C# events sample code. I'm sure you'll find a lot of content.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing *delegate* signature and signature of delegate *constructor*.

Delegate signature is `void (object, EventArgs)`, but delegate constructor (you call it via `new System.EventHandler(...)`) expects a single *method* with signature above, not a pair of arguments.

Note, that explicit constructor call could be omitted:

```
this.baptismApplication_add_button.Click += this.baptismApplication_add_button_Click;
```

Compiler will convert this into `EventHandler` constructor call.

Comment: Thank you I understand now :)

Comment: @DonovanKeating If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it!

Comment: I just have another confusion. Let me repost my comment again.

Comment: But in which part does the sender and EventArgs get passed as argument? I can't seem to find it in my code.

Comment: @DonovanKeating: `sender` and `e` are passed by delegate caller. In particular, when button is clicked, it looks if there are any event handlers, and calls them, passing itself as `sender` and `EventArgs.Empty` as `e`. This is what delegates are invented for - you pass a reference to your method (delegate) to some code, and later that code calls your method, providing required arguments.

Comment: But in the case of noncustome events, the passing of arguments isn't shown in the generated code. Am I right?

Comment: @DonovanKeating: this is not about custom/non-custom. Your method will be called from code, located in another assembly. Generated code (assuming, that we're talking about WinForms designer) just *registers* your method as delegate. It doesn't *call* given method.

Answer (score 0):

```
+= new System.EventHandler(this.baptismApplication_add_button_Click);
```

Should be

```
+= new System.EventHandler(myhandler);
```

where `myhandler` is a handler method with proper matching arguments per delegate definition like

```
private void myhandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you I understand now :). But in which part does the sender and EventArgs get passed as argument? I can't seem to find it in my code.